How common is it for languages with declension to decline names like nouns?
This question pertains specifically to languages that both have case-marking on nouns and do that case-marking through declension rather than solely things like adpositions.
Some Indo-European languages with declension do this, for example Russian:

"Мальчик видит меня." - "The boy sees me."
"Я вижу мальчика." - "I see the boy."
"Юрий видит меня." - "Yuri sees me."
"Я вижу Юрия." - "I see Yuri."

However, others don't, such as Urdu:

"بچہ مجھے دیکھتا ہے" - "The boy sees me."
"میں بچے کو دیکھتی ہوں" - "I see the boy."
"حمزہ مجھے دیکھتا ہے" - "Hamza sees me."
"میں حمزہ کو دیکھتی ہوں" - "I see Hamza."

Personally, as someone whose first languages are English and Urdu, it was surprising to learn that declining names was common in the Indo-European language family. How common is it across languages with declension overall?

Even English declines proper names for the only category left in declension, namely number, e.g., the two Philipps or *the Lannisters'.

@SirCornflakes I should've clarified, I was specifically curious about case

I can't speak to a particularly broad overview, but Arabic and Akkadian also decline names just like other nouns. Afaict that also seems to have been the case in all the old Indo-European languages. From my (limited) knowledge it seems that Urdu is unusual in this respect

I wasn’t aware that Urdu (and Hindi?) doesn’t decline names. I don’t recall ever coming across such a feature before. Certainly all other Indo-European languages I’m familiar with do, as well as Basque, Korean, Uralic and Inuit languages; I’m no Semitist, but as far as I know, Semitic languages do too. I know of several inflectional languages that decline nouns but not adjectives, but I don’t think I’ve ever even considered the possibility of declining common nouns but not proper nouns.

@JanusBahsJacquet I wonder if it might be related to the way Biblical names were frequently borrowed into Latin as indeclinable. I could see how a sufficiently large influx of foreign (presumably largely Arabic) names into Urdu could lead to the class of indeclinable names becoming the norm, potentially with that indeclinability spreading to other names, but that would require a very particular set of historical events that are unlikely to have occurred very often

I suspect indigenous fusional languages would be more likely to have this set of circumstances, as they'd be likely to receive a high number of prestigious loan names at a time, and also would be less able to incorporate them into their existing morphology than analytic or agglutinative languages would

I believe Hindi (including Urdu) does decline names, though not all surface forms are unique.  This is true of Russian or English, two relative extremes, as well, but the degree varies wildly.

I had been wondering if Hindi/Urdu could be analyzed as putting all names into one of the noun classes that don't decline for case when singular, but I thought that seemed like a bit of a strange analysis given an example like the one I presented in the question, where the Perso-Arabic loans بچہ and حمزہ get declined differently despite ending the same way phonemically and orthographically. There is some irregularity to how nouns get classed though, it isn't completely determined by ending for all nouns, so that could be a reasonable analysis.

Modern Greek declines names that are nouns.

You asked whether it is common for languages to decline proper nouns in the same way as common nouns. The answer is that this is very common and that it is uncommon for proper nouns not to be declined. You cited the example of Urdu. There is a similar (though not identical) situation in German. Here, masculine and neuter proper nouns are declined like common nouns (as in: Ludwigs Haus), but do not take case endings in the other cases. The exact German equivalents of your four sentences are:
Der Knabe sieht mich.
Ich sehe den Knaben.
Der Karl sieht mich.
Ich sehe den Karl.
In the last example “Karl” is grammatically accusative and can take the accusative article “den”, but the noun is not visibly conjugated. This is the rule in modern German, though in Early New High German, for example in Luther’s translation of the Bible, proper nouns can be declined, usually in their Latin form, e.g. nominative Jesus, dative Jesu, accusative Jesum, and modern German retains this in a few set phrases, like Mariä Himmelfahrt “Mary’s ascension”.

The normal German noun Kerl  "guy, bloke" (cognate to the given name Karl) also doesn't have an accusative ending: Ich sehe den Kerl, so the example is not good. Better examples can be found with surnames: Ich sehe (den) Bauer (surname) vs. Ich sehe den Bauern (noun, "I see the farmer"). The use of article+surname is non-standard and regional, but not uncommon.

@SirCornflakes Bauer/Bauern is a good example.
